# PHP Laravel - Allow users to use a custom domain name

Tags: php, apache, laravel, dns

I've looked through pretty much every single page I could find on the topic, but I'm still bit confused.

I have a PHP Laravel 4.0 web site, which is at

http://www.mywebsite.com

When a user signs up, each user gets their own page

http://user1.mywebsite.com

I have set the above via wildcard sub domain on my VPS DNS manager (Linode).

And in my Laravel, I have a domain route that picks up the subdomain and displayes the correct user's page. All works well.

Now, what I want to achieve is have a user use their own domain name and point to their page on my website.

So if a user signs up with

http://www.user1domain.com

I'd like this domain to point to http://user1.mywebsite.com

I do not want a redirect, but the URL to remain at http://www.user1domain.com (obviously).

I know that sites like Tumblr allows this.

What steps do I take in achieving this? Here are somethings I thought of during my research.

1. Have the user to make their custom domain "user1domain.com" to point to my VPS name server (easy).
2. On my end (here's where I fall short), do I

   - Create a new DNS entry? (In my Linode VPS, I would do this in "DNS Manager" and "Add a domain zone")
   - I'm using Apache, so do I have to create a VirtualHost (like I do for all of my other sites), does this mean I have to create a new VirtualHost file for every user who wants to use a custom domain?
   - If NOT VirtualHost, how do I actually point to my web application folder? Apache alias? (How do I set that up?)
3. Assuming the user's domain name now "points" to my web application, how do I now pick that up in Laravel? (I'm guessing I'd do this the same way I do for my sub domains)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: ask the user to use a CNAME entry pointing to their url in your site?

Comment: hi @itachi. Do you mean user1domain.com to alias to user1.mywebsite.com via CNAME? What if CNAME isn't available for the user? Isn't pointing to the "nameserver" ok?

Comment: I'm a little confused on http://www.user1domain.com pointing to http://user1.mywebsite.com but URL to remain http://www.user1domain.com. That does not make much sense. Do you just want to say http://www.user1domain.com must point to the same host and the same code as http://www.mywebsite.com? With your one codebase knowing what to do by detecting from what domain name the request is from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Question: Create a new DNS entry? (In my Linode VPS, I would do this in "DNS Manager" and "Add a domain zone")

Answer: Yes, you'll need to ask your user to point their domain to your nameserver. You'll also have to add their domains into your DNS Manager.

> Question: I'm using Apache, so do I have to create a VirtualHost (like I do for all of my other sites), does this mean I have to create a new VirtualHost file for every user who wants to use a custom domain?
>
> If NOT VirtualHost, how do I actually point to my web application folder? Apache alias? (How do I set that up?)

Answer: You can set up just one virtual host configuration for all, as documented in [Using *default* vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default).

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysharedsite
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So all domain names that are requesting to your server will be served by your only one code base.

> Question: Assuming the user's domain name now "points" to my web application, how do I now pick that up in Laravel? (I'm guessing I'd do this the same way I do for my sub domains)

I can think of two ways right now. Yes you could adapt Laravel's documentation on [Sub-Domain Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing), but use for different domains instead:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'user1domain.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('blog/{id}', 'BlogController@view');
});
```

But I suppose that functionalities will be quite the same between different domains, it's only the data that changes, you could use always use:

```
Request::getHost();
```

So you get the domain, and perhaps map it to a website_id column in your database to get the correct content.

Make sure you whitelist the acceptable domain names carefully in your project. Letting all domain names in isn't a good idea. You could limit by using `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` in your virtual host as well, but I guess that limits the flexibility of letting new users have their own domains.

Comment: This is great. However, when using this method, how can I easily turn of the SSL.

Comment: How about on LEMP Server sir @Unnawut ?

Comment: In this day and age, I feel HTTPS must be included as part of the answer and using the default VirtualHost does not allow for it

Answer (score 0):

The above answer suggested pointing domain to the main applications nameservers. In most cases that wouldn't be ideal as you might want to still use the domain other sub-domains/emails with other providers.

So an A record with the IP to the application, is the best case as it let's your customers have the control to their domain

Answer (score -1):

Basicly for created dynamic wildcard you just need this..

1. setup your wildcard on domain (A Record) to your server ip address

   ```
   *.mywebsite.com IN A 192.168.1.1
   ```
2. Setup Your servername & serveralias Apache Conf for domain name inside VirtualHost

   ```
   ServerName mywebsite.com

   ServerAlias mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com
   ```
3. clear dnscache on window console

   ```
   ipconfig/flushdns
   ```

hope this help

Comment: This response is specific to subdomains and windows. The op has asked about top level domains. Please consider revising.