# Laravel - A SaaS that allows a user to use his own domain to redirect to SaaS subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

I have a SaaS application built using Laravel, the user registers and gets a subdomain (e.g. myapp.domain.com), but during the registration process the user might choose to use his own domain instead of this subdomain, so there's a field that allows him to enter the desired domain (e.g. anotherdomain.com)

Normally, I do this manually by adding an entry to the virtual hosts. However i wonder if there's anyway to achieve this in Laravel

Has anyone tried this before ?

Comment: You didn't mention which web server you use. If you are using Nginx, the virtual host with the "default_server" flag (in the configuration file) receives all the requests that don't match any virtual host. In Laravel, you can create a middleware to detect the requested domain by HTTP request header and behave according to it.

Comment: Please see this link this may help you.
[PHP Laravel - Allow users to use a custom domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327868/php-laravel-allow-users-to-use-a-custom-domain-name)